# Unexpected error in PHP

Tags: php

I get the following error. I checked the Stack Overflow post for situations like that but I couldn't figure it out,i really looked inside the code for around 30 minutes. I'd be really thankful for anyone who could help me with this error. I think my brackets are completely messed up...
The error is :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\photographer\includes\signup.inc.php on line 20

The signup.inc.php file code is :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

$first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
$last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

//error handler
//checking for empty fields
if(empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($uid) ||         
empty($pwd) ) {
    header("Location: register.php?register=empty");
    exit();

}   else {
    //check if input characters are valid 
 if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", 
$last) {
    header("Location: register.php?register=invalid");
    exit();
}       else {
            //check if e-mail is valid
        if (filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            header("Location: register.php?register=email");
            exit();

        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid'";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                header("Location: register.php?register=usertaken");
                exit();

            } else {
                // hashing pass
                $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                //insert the user in db 
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, 
  user_email, user_uid, user_pwd) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', 
 '$uid', '$hashedPwd');";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header ("Location: register.php?register=succes");
                exit();

            }


        }


        }

    }



else {
header("Location: register.php");
exit();


}

?>
```

Thanks in advance for anyone that might answer my question!

Comment: I think that's already pretty self-explanatory. Whats on line 20?

Comment: @hungrykoala the first if statement, it doesn't work,i tried removing adding etc

Comment: My suggestion is to fix your formatting. Only then it will be clear which bracket was creating the error

Comment: if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", 
$last) { close the if here, missing ")"

Comment: You're also using two else simultaneously. if(){}else{}else{}

Comment: the formatting can be improved. Also it's full of if { else { if { why not to use else if { ?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a `)` Change:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last) {
```

to:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last)) {
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.Now it generated a new error.. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\photographer\includes\signup.inc.php on line 59 idk what's happening with ym code tbh

Comment: Because you're using two else. You can't have if(){}else{}else{}

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting your else-if statements in the following format instead:

```
if ($a < "1") {
    echo "";
} elseif ($a < ">1") {
echo "Hello world!";
}
```

So where you have things such as:

```
 else {
    //check if input characters are valid 
 if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", 
$last)};
```

rewrite them using elseif.

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a  and '{' and '); Change:

add ')' at the end of the the if block as told by @manassehkatz

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last)) {
```

and add another one '}' before the

```
else {
header("Location: register.php");
exit();
}
```

There must be 5 '}' before the above given else to close all the bracket and you have only 4 '}'.